# Adding Variable Integers But Outputting as Strings - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm having a small issue adding variables together, I have a input number field set up to set the variable. Then all I'm then trying to do is post 3 numbers the first is the original, the second is the first plus the original, then the third is the second plus the original. But for some reason (clearly I'm missing something) as my variables are outputting as strings rather than integers?

```js
function submit() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var p1 = parseInt(input);
  var p2 = parseInt(p1) + input;
  var p3 = parseInt(p2) + input;
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = p1;
  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = p2;
  document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = p3;
}
```

```html
<label for="input">Value</label><br>
<input type="number" id="input"><br>
<button id="btnSubmit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<p id="p1">0</p>
<p id="p2">0</p>
<p id="p3">0</p>
```

Comment: "Fastest Gun in the West" type of question. [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731) [2](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/10/06/solving-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/)

Comment: @user7393973 So...who won?

Comment: Javascript `+` doesn't decide the mode of operation depending only on the first operand but on both: "If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then". If either is a string, you are getting a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you do your arithmetic with numbers everywhere, consistently:

```js
function submit() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var p1 = parseInt(input);
    var p2 = 2*p1;
    var p3 = p2 + p1;
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = p1;
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = p2;
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = p3;
}
```

```html
<label for="input">Value</label><br>
<input type="number" id="input"><br>
<button id="btnSubmit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<p id="p1">0</p>
<p id="p2">0</p>
<p id="p3">0</p>
```

This is just an issue with JavaScript interpreting the expression as string concatenation versus arithmetic, the latter which is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById("input").value returns a string value, you need to convert it to integer type. Use `parseInt` on `input` variable declaration instead doing it everywhere else.

```
  var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value);
```

```js
function submit() {
  var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value, 10);
  var p1 = input;
  var p2 = p1 + input;
  var p3 = p2 + input;
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = p1;
  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = p2;
  document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = p3;
}
```

```html
<label for="input">Value</label><br>
<input type="number" id="input"><br>
<button id="btnSubmit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<p id="p1">0</p>
<p id="p2">0</p>
<p id="p3">0</p>
```

Comment: Note that your explanation, while good coding advice, does not actually touch on what is going wrong with the OP's logic.

Comment: I was in the middle of updating the answer only. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing string concatenation. use `parseInt()` to get the integer representation for your `input`

```js
    function submit() {
      var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
      var p1 = parseInt(input);
      var p2 = parseInt(p1) + parseInt(input);
      var p3 = parseInt(p2) + parseInt(input);
      document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = p1;
      document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = p2;
      document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = p3;
    }
```

```html
 <label for="input">Value</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="input"><br>
    <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
    <p id="p1">0</p>
    <p id="p2">0</p>
    <p id="p3">0</p>
```

Comment: There's no point in calling `parseInt` on a number.  `p1` is a number, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

`input` is a string, which is why you're using `parseInt(input)` to cast it to an integer.

The line `var p2 = parseInt(p1) + input;` does for an input of, let's say, `"42"` as follows: `var p2 = parseInt(parseInt("42")) + "42";`, which means you concatenate a string instead of adding two integers.

You can either use `var p2 = p1 + parseInt(input);` or just `var p2 = p1 * 2;` and `var p3 = p1 * 3`, which is probably a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript `'1' + 1 = 11` so what are you doing is

```
p1 = parseInt(1) //input = 1

p2 = 1 + '1' // p1 = 1, input = '1' 
output = '11'

p3 = 1 + '11' // p2 = 1, input = '1'
output = '111'
```

you should parse your input instead of p1

here is updated snippet

```js
function submit() {
  var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value);
  var p1 = input;
  var p2 = p1 + input;
  var p3 = p2 + input;
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = p1;
  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = p2;
  document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = p3;
}
```

```html
<label for="input">Value</label><br>
<input type="number" id="input"><br>
<button id="btnSubmit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<p id="p1">0</p>
<p id="p2">0</p>
<p id="p3">0</p>
```